# NvarChar (Max) column in Azure App service Tables saves empty string for a large data

Tags: sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

When I try to convert the byte arrays for an Image (& an audio file, created in a Xamarin Forms app) to JSON & save it to an azure App Service SQL backend in a NVARCHAR(Max) column, it completely omits that record & saves a blank string instead.

Here is a sample of the JSON file that gets created. 
[Large Json Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzYXG8uD6JT3X3hmNFNZWnBrQm8)

when the json file does not have byte arrays, the resulting string data saves fine.

Rest of the data in corresponding columns also saves just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't upload and place in the database.  Place it in a storage account.  For a blog on how to do this (roughly), see https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/30/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-27-file-handling-v1/ and https://shellmonger.com/2016/06/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-28-file-handling-v2/

If you aren't using Xamarin and/or Cordova, there are similar SDKs for v1 handling in iOS and Android.  File Sync only works in .NET right now though.

Comment: The idea is to definitely save it in a storage account. But given my context, I wanted to check if I could somehow save it in DB. 

To give you some context, in my xamarin mobile app, in order to retrieve the list of bytes I will have to dig into a lot of entities. (Templates->Sections->Controls & then figure out the controls & if they are blob type then update the bytes in blob & get a URL) 

My save from mobile is already very slow because I do an azure offline sync of a lot of data. My idea was to pass the data in DB from where the associated web app can pick it up & save in storage

Comment: If your app is slow when doing offline sync, make sure you are doing incremental sync (UpdatedAt field and Version field in your client-side model, plus named query in your PullAsync() call).

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I was using incremental sync initially, but turns out, it does not always return all the data that it should. Although a bit slow, but not passing the query key ensures 100% that I get all record sets.

Comment: There was a bug in the v2.2.1 Node.js backend SDK when used with SQLite data store.  This caused incremental sync to not work correctly.  Install v2.2.0 (or wait for the fix in v3.0 later this week)  You can read about the bug here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/496